# ¿Cómo hacer uso de la variable *errors* si estoy usando AJAX en Laravel 7?

Tags: laravel, ajax, laravel-7

```html
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        

        $request->validate([
            'equ_Nombre' => 'required'
        ]);

        $datosEquipo = request()->except('_token');

        equipoModel::insert($datosEquipo);

        return response()->json();
        
        /* return Response()->json($msg); */
    }
```

estoy intentando hacer CRUD con Laravel 7 usando la tecnología AJAX pero cuando intento registrar, quiero usar la variable ***errors*** para mostrar los errores en cada input como se haría normalmente si no se usa AJAX. Pero leyendo la documentación oficial de Laravel, dice que cuando se usa AJAX Request, no genera una respuesta de redirección, sino una respuesta JSON.

Hay alguna manera de de usar esta variable usando AJAX o de llenarla a partir del response JSON.
El formulario lo usa a partir de un modal de bootstrap. Y el codigo Jquery con el que uso AJAX lo intento reutilizar para las demás entidades de la base de datos.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
$('button[name=guardar]').click(function (e) {
        console.log('sdf');
        e.preventDefault();
        form = $(this).parents('form');
        token = $('input[name=_token]').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr('action'),
            headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        })
        
    })
```

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-dialog-scrollable modal-sm">
            <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header bg-dark text-white">
                      <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Añadir equipo</h5>
                  </div>
                  <form action="{{ url('personal/equipo') }}" method="POST" id="nose" name="">
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <!--FORMULARIO REGISTRAR-->
                    @csrf
                            <div class="mb-3">
                              <label class="form-label">Nombre</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="equ_Nombre" autocomplete="off"
                              autofocus="true" placeholder="Ingrese el nombre del producto">
                            </div>
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label class="form-label">Cantidad</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="equ_Stock" autocomplete="off"
                                required placeholder="Ingrese la cantidad del equipo">
                              </div>
                            <div class="mb-3">
                              <label class="form-label">Precio</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="equ_PrecioBase" autocomplete="off"
                              required placeholder="Ingrese el precio del equipo">
                            </div>
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="exampleFormControlSelect2">Tipo de equipo</label>
                                <select multiple class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect2" name="equ_Tipo">
                                    <option disabled class="text-muted">--- Seleccione la categoría ---</option>
                                    @foreach ($categorias as $categoria)
                                        <option value="{{ $categoria['tip_idTipoEquipo'] }}">
                                            {{ $categoria['tip_Nombre'] }}
                                        </option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                            </div>
                      </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="guardar">Guardar</button>
                  </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Podrias publicar el codigo de la foto escrito porfavor?

Answer (score 1):

Debe retornar el los errores así

```
$rules = [
        'equ_Nombre' => 'required',
    ];

$messages = [
    'equ_Nombre.required' => 'El nombre es requerido.',
    ];


$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages);


if ($validator->passes()) {

    // si pasa tu logica

}else{
    return response()->json([
            'type' => 'validate',
            'errors' => $validator->errors()
        ]);

}
```

y después en js los puedes obtener y procesar así

```
$.post('{{ route('....') }}', data, function (data) {
    if (data.type === 'input-errors') {
        for (const prop in data.errors) {
            console.log(data.errors[prop][0])
        }
    }
});
```