# ¿Cómo poner el mensaje de error de validación debajo del input Laravel Ajax

Tags: laravel, ajax

Hola buenas tenia un formulario sin ajax el cual si no ingresaba el campo me mostraba debajo del input el mensaje de error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El tema va que ahora lo estoy haciendo con AJAX y me gustaria tambien que se pudiera mostrar así el mensaje de error, y no tener que crear un div o un alert con una lista de todos los errores, para asi mantener la estetica del sitio web.

Actualamente lo estoy probando asi con fallas para que me haga la validación cosa que funciona ya que en NETWORK me arroja un error 422 y que es el error de validación de 1 campo que no fue ingresado y todo lo hace el controlador.

Porque actualmente me genera el error pero no se me presenta en la vista o como quisiera que se mostrara el error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Formulario:

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => route('account.store'), 'name' =>
'create_account', 'id' => 'submit_account']) !!}
@csrf
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-3">
            {!! Form::Label('name', __('Nombre empresa *')) !!}

            {!! FormBuilder::text('name', $model, $errors) !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-3">
            {!! Form::Label('email', __('Email empresa')) !!}

            {!! FormBuilder::text('email', $model, $errors) !!}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary account-register">Guardar</button>

</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Controlador:

```
$validator = $this->validator($request->all())->validate();
   
        Account::create($request->all());
    
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            if ($validator->fails()) {
                return response()->json(['success' => false, 'errors' => $validator->errors()], 422);
            }

            return response()->json(['mensaje' => $request->all()]);
        }

        //Formulario proviene desde web y no de AJAX
        return redirect::to('account')
            ->with('success','Cuenta creada satisfactoriamente.');
```

Ajax:

```
document.getElementById("submit_account").addEventListener("submit", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var formData = new FormData(this);
            console.log(formData);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: $(this).attr('action'),
                data: {
                    "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",

                },
                success: function(){

                },
                error: function(jqXhr, json, errorThrown){
                    var errors = jqXhr.responseJSON;
                }
            })

        });
```

Comment: No se termina de entender el problema

Comment: @BetaM como poner el mensaje de error de la validación debajo del input

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo hacer uso de la variable \*errors\* si estoy usando AJAX en Laravel 7?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/387633/c%c3%b3mo-hacer-uso-de-la-variable-errors-si-estoy-usando-ajax-en-laravel-7)